# All http request to a particular script returns GET /false HTTP/1.1

Tags: http, nginx, service-worker, web-push

Whenever I'm trying to open web application my Nginx access log shows "GET /false HTTP/1.1" 404 206 "https://www.example.com/FeedifySW.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Micromax Q4260 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.85 Mobile Safari/537.36"  - -
I have searched through all way possible and still couldn't find the solution. Can anyone help?

This is for an nginx server where i have hosted my web application. due to high request counts, sometimes the application crashes

"GET /false HTTP/1.1" 404 206 "https://www.example.com/FeedifySW.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Micromax Q4260 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.85 Mobile Safari/537.36"  - -

Comment: Is your web application public? If yes, can you share the URL?

Comment: @shaochuancs yeah sure.  https://www.freshersworld.com/